# mmap() vs malloc() return address

Tags: c, linux, posix, x86-64

Why does `mmap()` return a 64 bit address while `malloc()` returns a 32 bit address ?

```c
char *a = (char *)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
printf("%p\n", a); // example: 0x7fbfbb065000

char *b = (char *)malloc(10); // example: 0x23bf010
printf("%p\n", b);
```

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` (or `mmap`) in a C program.

Comment: This is completely implementation-dependent and uninteresting.

Comment: try gain and check again

Comment: Try asking for larger sizes from `malloc`.

Comment: Dietrich beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel places the memory heap in the lower 4GB, and that's why malloc(3) returns a 64-bit address with all of the upper 32-bit cleared.

You can add a sleep at the end of your code, and recompile & run the program again. Then read "/proc/Process_ID/maps" and you will see that the heap is in the lower 4GB:

% cat /proc/26375/maps

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 46177                              /root/c/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 46177                              /root/c/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 46177                              /root/c/a.out
01e03000-01e24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f654038c000-7f6540541000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f6540541000-7f6540740000 ---p 001b5000 ca:01 395503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f6540740000-7f6540744000 r--p 001b4000 ca:01 395503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f6540744000-7f6540746000 rw-p 001b8000 ca:01 395503                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f6540746000-7f654074b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f654074b000-7f654076d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 395517                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f6540960000-7f6540963000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f654096a000-7f654096d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f654096d000-7f654096e000 r--p 00022000 ca:01 395517                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f654096e000-7f6540970000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 395517                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff4445e000-7fff4447f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff44500000-7fff44501000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really just an implementation detail of your `malloc()` and `mmap()` implementations.  Try changing the allocation size to 16 MiB, you'll probably see very similar results from `mmap()` and `malloc()`.

On a Unix system, allocated memory usually comes from one of two system calls: `sbrk()` and `mmap()`, so a `malloc()` implementation will typically call one of those two functions.  The `malloc()` function is a library function, not a syscall, you see (which explains why it's in section 3 of the manual, while `sbrk()` and `mmap()` are in section 2).

For small allocations, such as 10 bytes in your example, `malloc()` will typically group many allocations into one larger allocation, and some implementations use `sbrk()`.  For large allocations, such as 16 MiB in my example, `malloc()` will just call `mmap()` and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has 64-bit pointers, both return a 64-bit address.  It just so happens that `malloc` is giving you back one with the top 32 bits set to 0.  Why that is is completely dependent on your implementation - since your question is tagged <kbd>linux</kbd>, you can go look into the sources to find out!